# Error : All estimators should implement fit and transform, or can be 'drop' or 'passthrough' specifiers. StandardScaler() doesn't

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, sklearn-pandas, scikit-learn-pipeline

I am trying to implement a model that uses ColumnTransformer() followed by SVC().

My transform method looks like:

```
num_features = X_train_svm.select_dtypes(include=np.number).columns.to_list()
cat_features = X_train_svm.select_dtypes(include=['object']).columns.to_list()

transform1 = make_column_transformer([(StandardScaler(), num_features),
                                      (OneHotEncoder(), cat_features)
                                      ])
```

Followed by a pipeline:

```
pipe = make_pipeline(transform1, svm.SVC())
```

Then when i try to fit train and test data :

```
pipe.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

I get the error :: TypeError: All estimators should implement fit and transform, or can be 'drop' or 'passthrough' specifiers. '(StandardScaler(), ['Height', 'Age', 'Weight', 'Quantity', 'Cost'])' (type <class 'tuple'>) doesn't.

Please help me fix this error.

I tried changing scaler to Ordinal Scaler, tried reshaping the data using (-1,1), but nothing worked.

Answer (score 3):

The transformers given to `make_column_transformer` shouldn't be contained in a list: they are separate positional arguments. See the example in [the docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.compose.make_column_transformer.html).

In your example, just delete the square brackets in the definition of `transform1`.