# TypeError: All estimators should implement fit and transform, or can be 'drop' or 'passthrough' specifiers

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, data-science, typeerror

```
# Numerical Pipeline 
num_pipeline=Pipeline(
  steps=[
    ('imputer',KNNImputer(n_neighbors=3,missing_values=np.nan)),
    ('scaler',MinMaxScaler()),
    ('sampling',RandomOverSampler())
  ]
)
            
# Categorical Pipeline
cat_pipeline=Pipeline(
  steps=[
    ('imputer',KNNImputer(n_neighbors=3,missing_values = np.nan)),
  ]
)
preprocessor=ColumnTransformer([
  ('num_pipeline',num_pipeline,numerical_cols),
  ('cat_pipeline',cat_pipeline,categorical_cols)
])
return preprocessor
logging.info('Pipeline completed')
```

I tried running these pipelines but getting this error:

> TypeError: All estimators should implement fit and transform, or can be 'drop' or 'passthrough' specifiers. 'Pipeline(steps=[('imputer', SimpleImputer(strategy='most_frequent')),
> ('scaler', MinMaxScaler()), ('sampling', RandomOverSampler())])' (type <class 'sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline'>) doesn't.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error : All estimators should implement fit and transform, or can be 'drop' or 'passthrough' specifiers. StandardScaler() doesn't](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71566189/error-all-estimators-should-implement-fit-and-transform-or-can-be-drop-or)

Comment: Please read the [description](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/ml/info) of the ML tag.

Comment: @DataJanitor not a duplicate, because the object in question is a Pipeline not a tuple like there. // I suspect the problem is that you're using sklearn's pipeline, but with the imblearn resampler in there you need imblearn's pipeline.

Comment: That said, it will fail anyway when you try to increase the number of rows in the numerical columns but not in the categorical columns...